# Variable time.sleep(X.XX ) FPS outcome on AWS vs localhost

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services

My asynchronous script has a main loop that runs 150 000 iterations per second on my local machine, and roughly 180 000 iterations per second on an AWS instance (Windows AMI, Python 3.7).

When I introduce time.sleep(1 / X) on this loop, I manage to throttle it nicely on my local host.  Example:

```
while t - tzero < settings.main_loop_seconds:
    for singleobject in iterable:
        singleobject.process()     
        t= time.time()
        time.sleep(1/10000)  
        """with this I expect a maximum of 10000 iterations per second, and with the time lost to 'process' I get an actual 6500 iterations per second. As expected."""
        loopcounter += 1
        """ I reset this loopcounter to 0 from another thread (using threading.Timer)  It is used for logging the number of loops per second.
```

The problem now, on AWS, same code, just changing "X" in time.sleep( 1 / X) .

X = 1  # I get 1 loop per second

X = 10 # I get 9 loops per second

X = 100 #I get 64 loops per second

X = 1000 #I get 64 loops per second

X = 10000 #I get 64 loops per second

X = 100000 #I get 64 loops per second

Can someone help explain the behavior?  Thank you.